# SQL Decimal points to be remove extra values.?

Tags: sql

I have some case about 8.89291 value in SQL database.

In this case if I'm running:

```
select cast(ROUND(8.89291,0) as float)
```

The output is : 9

What I'm actually looking for is

The output is : 8.9

How can I get this value?

Will you guys please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `precision` is 0 so its giving the whole value.

```
select cast(round(8.89291, 1) as float)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to casting, then you don't also need to call `ROUND`.  Consider casting to `NUMERIC(10,1`):

```
SELECT CAST(8.89291 AS NUMERIC(10,1));
```

### Demo

(demo for SQL Server, but the above would run on many other databases as well)

Comment: this is better approach , round not needed

Answer (score 1):

You had selected `0` that mean float function will treat as `Integer` ,for the `float` you have to put 1 instead of 0 ,please check below one.

```
select cast(ROUND(8.89291,1) as float)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(8.89291,2) AS NUMERIC(12,1))
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(8.89291 AS NUMERIC(12,1))
```